# How smart is iTunes or iPhone's shuffle function?

Tags: itunes, ipod

Is iTunes shuffle function is just a programming language `random()` function or it's smarter than that? Does it use play count, skip count and other parameters to play better songs first?

Comment: Would the question be better phrased as, "How random is iTunes or iPhone's shuffle function?"

Answer (score 2):

This has been a point for discussion [for a very long time!](http://blog.enkerli.com/2005/03/29/ipoditunes-shuffle-mode-really-totally-random/)

Here's a great article looking at this exact issue - [How Much Does iTunes Like My Five-Star Songs?](http://www.omninerd.com/articles/How_Much_Does_iTunes_Like_My_Five_Star_Songs) Bear in mind this is from 2005 but I see very similar behaviour to what is described here.

The standout image for me is this one:
[image]

It shows pretty clearly that shuffle does use rating in determining which song to play. I find it strange that mid-rated songs are much more likely to be played than high-rated songs.

AskDifferent user [Ian C.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/292/ian-c) did some interesting experiments [last year](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/23205/3117) and found that the appearing non-randomness of shuffle is probably due to the algorithm re-using the seed rather than being completely random.

The meaning of this is that shuffle is not truly random, only pseudorandom. As this [Random Seed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) article (Wikipedia) explains, having the seed used in a pseudorandom process will allow you to recreate the same "random" results. True randomness is actually very, very hard to get. (While working on a mobile phone at Siemens years ago a doctor of mathematics had to be brought in to write the random function - the ordinary programmers weren't considered qualified, and the C library function considered inadequate.)

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted that graph.  It shows a typical library that **contains more mid-rated songs** than high or low rated songs.  The blue represents the normal shuffle and yellow the *play higher rated songs more often* (or *rating biased*) shuffle.  So it shows that *rating biased* shuffle will play your higher rated songs more often than it would in normal shuffle.