# iOS Music App Repeats Songs When Shuffled

Tags: iphone, music, ios

For the past week or so, my Music app has been playing songs at least a couple of times before it gets through every song, which is pretty frustrating.

My library is >1000 songs (filled a 64GB iPhone with almost entirely uncompressed music) but I'm hearing the same song a couple of times in the morning while at work, and I haven't changed songs manually, just let the shuffle do its thing.

Is there a reason for this? I am on iOS 9.2.1, but I don't see anything about this in the change log for the newest iOS, although I'm updating it now because this problem is very annoying.

This also happens in my playlists (for example my KPOP playlist with ~50 songs, which is much easier to see happen) where it doesn't seem to keep track of the songs it has already played and not play those songs until the shuffle has finished each song once.

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23194/why-isnt-itunes-shuffle-random/23205#23205

Comment: Not related, this is a very different problem

Comment: I've been seeing similar 'songs repeated when on shuffle' questions on this and Apple's forums for almost 2 years.  Everyone has slightly different ways to resolve it but most people never have it solved.  I hope you find an answer to your issue but I don't think this will ever, truly, be solved for everyone.